# Updating content size height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` consisting of a `UITableView` tucked below a `UIView`. The `UITableView` has cells of dynamic height, and I'm having trouble setting the `contentSize` of the scroll view. If I set it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, it works fine, but calling it from `viewDidLoad` won't work. Calling it from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is a problem though because that function is refreshing every few seconds, and I'm not sure how to change the contentSize of the scrollView if I add a new element to the tableView. This is what I have so far:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {
      self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
   }) { (complete) in
      print(self.tableView.contentSize.height)
      self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height

      self.scrollView.contentSize.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height + self.view.frame.width/2 + 10                    
      print(self.scrollView.contentSize.height)
   }
}
```

So my question is really, how can I make it work from viewDidLoad?

Comment: May I know why are you changing the content size of scroll view ? If possible also add the screenshot of what the problem.

Comment: If I don't then the scrollView is unscrollable

Comment: Bsically, UITableView itself is a subclass of scrollview, Just by having a single UITableView inside the view controller should have been a better approach. But why are you using a UIScrollView -> UIView -> UITableView  instead ? Is there any particular reason ?

Comment: I'm updating a UISlider to update audio, and I want scrubbing to work smoothly. Using it in a UITableViewCell made it super glitchy

Comment: But it should have worked fine, There could be some issue in UI updation. If possible add some picture of your issue, then we could get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ( Dispatch.main.async After ) to call it from viewDidLoad , or you set it in viewDidLayoutSubviews and put resize code in if statement with once bool value to be executed one time by setting once = false inside the IF statement